# Why does DateTimeZone's getOffset() need a parameter?

Tags: php

**What's the point of PHP's [DateTimeZone::getOffset](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php)'s (timezone_offset_get) `datetime` parameter?**

```
<?php

$tz = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");

var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime())); // 32400
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Taipei')))); // 32400
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest')))); // 32400
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')))); // 32400
```

Am I missing something, or the parameter doesn't affect the output of the function at all?

The documentation mentions the function computes the offset from/for the parameter. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the offset depends on the date.

For example, in summer `Europe/Budapest` has an offset of 2 hours (because of daylight saving time), in winter of 1 hour:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Budapest");

var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2018-06-06', $tz))); // 7200
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2018-01-06', $tz))); // 3600
```

Daylight saving time is not the only source of change, see for example [Moscow time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time#History):

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Moscow");

var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2010-01-01', $tz))); // 10800
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2012-01-01', $tz))); // 14400
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2015-01-01', $tz))); // 10800
```